# Go + Revel: How to import custom package?

Tags: import, go, revel

I am following tutorial of chat room covered [here](http://revel.github.io/samples/chat.html)

I changed it to import a local package instead of using the sample from ravel's github. I changed it into something like this in one of the controllers (`refresh.go` in the tuts):

```
import (
    "./../chatroom"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
)
```

And chatroom was in the right directory:

```
- app
  - chatroom
    - chatroom.go
  - controllers
    - refresh.go
    - app.go
```

`package chatroom` was also initialized already in `chatroom.go`.

But when running the code, I received this error:

**The Go code app/tmp/main.go does not compile: local import "./../chatroom" in non-local package**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best, [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688069/6309) to not use a relative path, but a path from the `$GOPATH/src`

In your case, is `$GOPAHT/src` includes app chatroom, you would use

```
import app/chatroom
```

The OP comments:

> working, but I have to include my app name, something like `myapp/app/chatroom`,

That makes sense, if `$GOPATH/src` contains the folder `myapp`.

Comment: working but i have to include my app name, something like `myapp/app/chatroom`